# Xcode upload a plist file on a server (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, file-upload, plist

I have a simple (I think) question :

I got an iPhone. He create a plist file and he save it. I want to upload this file on a server.

Then, with 3 others iPhone, I will download this plist file and decrypt the informations.

My question is : How can I upload this plist file into a server !!
I don't have any  FTP server or others ... Can I use instead Dropbox by exemple ?
Or is an other way to communicate between iPhone (private - not for AppStore) ?

Thanks very much for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk) to upload a plist on the Dropbox user's folder.

Check first [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios) to setup your project

You can use these snippets ([from this page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios#uploading)):

```
NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *filename = @"Info.plist";
NSString *destDir = @"/";
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                   withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

then implement the callbacks

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
    from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error);
}
```

**EDIT**:
(if you want, you can load the plist from the Documents folder of your app. remember that the mainBundle is read-only so you can't modify the plist that resides in the main bundle, you can only read it)..like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *plistFilePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"info.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistFile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
```

Comment: You're a master !! Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: A little question (i'm sorry) !
How can i load the plist from the Documents folder of my app ? It's called "Menu.plist"

Thank you again !

Comment: @WaesAntoine Check my edit..remember to check the answer as accepted (and upvote it if you want) if it's useful for you :)